# DynamoDB - Why can't I use an "_" as a prefix in my key condition expression?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using the AWS DynamoDB DocumentClient to query my DynamoDB tables.  In my tables I have a property called "_id" that holds a unique ID for each entry.  When I try to query for a record based on this ID, I end up receiving an error that says: "Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: \"_\", near: \"_id\"".  The code that makes this query is below.

```
    function findById(id) {

     //Build query
    var params = {};
    params.TableName = "recordDev";
    params.IndexName = "_id";
    params.KeyConditionExpression = '_id = :id';
    params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
      ':id': id
    };

    return DynamoDB
        .query(params).promise()
        .then(function(records) {
          return records.Items[0];
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          return Promise.reject(error);
        });
   };
```

Is there something that I am missing with regards to using an "_" when building the query params for DynamoDB?  I have tried looking around for similar errors, but have been unable to find any that are like my scenario.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can you try using the ExpressionAttributeNames param?

```
var params = {};
params.TableName = "recordDev";
params.IndexName = "_id";
params.KeyConditionExpression = '#id = :id';
params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
  ':id': id
};
params.ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#id":"_id"
};
```

Comment: That worked!  Is there any reason that you know of for why it doesn't just automatically work without using ExpressionAttributeNames for things with "_"?

Comment: Really no idea. Most probably it has to do with their parsing mechanism.  I think in case of simple names it can work without specifying ExpressionAttributeNames, but not quite sure.

Comment: how do you do this with the aws cli?

Comment: @red888 you cannot put your own logics to mongo queries via aws-cli. You have to change it manually after you done creating your API.

Answer (score 8):

The same problem also occurs when you have "-" in property name. For example, I had "id-test" as the property name. I got the same error:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query
>   operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "-",
>   near: "teamid-testid"

The solution suggested by @gkatzioura works in this case too. Here is my implementation using Python boto3 conventions:

```
params = {}

params['TableName'] = "myTable"
params['ProjectionExpression']="idStatus"
params['KeyConditionExpression'] = 'scanid = :val1 and #idtest = :val2'
params['ExpressionAttributeValues'] = {":val1":{"S": scanid}, ":val2": {"S": id_test}}
params['ExpressionAttributeNames'] = {"#idtestid": "id-test"}
```

Comment: On the last line, I think `"#idtestid"` should be `"#idtest"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try for Java case this code:

```
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> itemValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
itemValues.put(":id", AttributeValue.builder().s(key).build());

QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest.builder().tableName("recordDev")
            .keyConditionExpression("_id = :id").expressionAttributeValues(itemValues).build();

QueryResponse queryResponse = dynamoDBClient.query(queryRequest);
```

Works for me.